# numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

**numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])**

I have a data set of N points and X dimensions. So when I compute numpy.mean(data, axis=0) and numpy.cov(data) and use the mean and cov values in numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov). It throws following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 3986, in mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:16833)
ValueError: mean and cov must have same length
```

Its because numpy.mean() computes mean column wise and gives an X dimensional array.
While output of numpy.cov() is a covariance matrix with N rows and X columns.
Can anyone suggest a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how `numpy.cov` interprets its first argument. You have each observation in a row, while [numpy.cov expects each observation in a column.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy.cov)

To fix, take the transpose of data in `np.cov(data.T)` to get the `X` x `X` covariance matrix:

```
In [58]: N, X = 100, 3

In [59]: data = np.random.random((N,X))

In [60]: mean = np.mean(data, axis = 0)

In [61]: mean
Out[61]: array([ 0.4913433 ,  0.49484566,  0.52463666])

In [62]: np.cov(data.T).shape
Out[62]: (3, 3)

In [63]: cov = np.cov(data.T)

In [64]: np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)
Out[64]: array([ 0.27194062,  0.65995531,  0.67367201])
```

Alternatively, use the `rowval=False` parameter:

```
In [68]: cov = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)

In [69]: cov.shape
Out[69]: (3, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Unutbu, I had missed that part somehow. Fixed now!